# Clone Object Javascript applying to all

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates, es6-class

and I trying to clone an object with Object assing.

> ```
> const defaults = {
>    a: [],
>    b: [],
>    c: [],
>    d: [],
>    e: [],
>    f: [],
>    g: []
> };
>
> this.rowSetSlug = Object.assign({},defaults);
> this.rowSetObject = Object.assign({},defaults);
> this.rowSetModified = Object.assign({},defaults);
> ```

But when I fill one object like

> ```
> this.rowSetObject.push(object);
> ```

And do a console.log()

```
console.log(this.rowSetObject);
console.log(this.rowSetModified);
console.log(this.rowSetSlug);
```

All same have the rowSetObject items, and if i fill another they replicate.

Thanks

Comment: This is due to the fact that you are cloning first level attributes, but when array values comes, them get _referenced_ beacause of object type. You have to deep clone your object, cloning every single array and paying attention that each element is not a reference object itself: only primitives are cloned by value: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-by-reference-vs-by-value-d49139beb1c4

Comment: First thanks for the awnser, has some function to do a deep clone? for each element on the array, or has to do a foreach ?!

Comment: There are a lot of libraries that provide deep clone, try _.deepClone() of lodash library (https://lodash.com/)